# Android MediaPlayer: video seek causes onSeekComplete to be called twice

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

What am I doing wrong here? I set up onSeekCompleteListener, I prepare a movie, I do a seek. Right away onSeekComplete is called. Then after a delay I play the movie. And then onSeekComplete is called again! Why again? Here is my code:

```
package com.test.seek;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;

public class SeekTestActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener {

    private SurfaceView sv;
    private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    private static final String TAG = SeekTestActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sv = new SurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(sv);
        sv.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        sv.getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
        try {
            mp.setDataSource( this, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.coverbutton_600x1024_05) );
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        mp.setDisplay( sv.getHolder() );
        Log.d(TAG,"preparing movie");
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"seeking");
        mp.seekTo(0);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG,"playing movie");
                mp.start();
            }
        }, 1000);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.d(TAG,"seek complete");

    }
}
```

And here is the LogCat:

```
05-12 09:18:38.446: D/SeekTestActivity(3857): preparing movie
05-12 09:18:38.446: D/AwesomePlayer(3543): AwesomePlayer Not VPX decoder = **video/avc** and video is = 600X1024
05-12 09:18:38.446: D/OMX_CORE(3543): TIOMX_GetHandle
05-12 09:18:38.446: E/OMX_PROXYDEC(3543): ___INSISDE VIDEO DECODER PROXY WRAPPER__
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/OMXCodec(3543): Flash Clip: Profile: 77, Level: 31, Interlaced: 0, RefFrames: 2
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/OMXCodec(3543): Updated. H264 Component profile 2 level 512 NRefFrames 2
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/OMXCodec(3543): initOutputFormat WxH 600x1024 Padded 768x1120
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/AwesomePlayer(3543):  initRenderer_l 768x1120
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/AwesomePlayer(3543):  initRenderer_l 600x1024
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/OMXCodec(3543): CodecRecommended O/P BufferCnt[9]
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/AwesomePlayer(3543): Codec Recommended outputBuffer count 9
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/TIOverlay(1419): Enabling the OVERLAY[0]
05-12 09:18:38.571: I/Overlay-V4L2(1419): Openning /dev/video1
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/TIOverlay(1419): Creating overlay from W768/H1120/FMT33 ...
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/TIOverlay(1419): mZorderUsage[0] is assigned to 0
05-12 09:18:38.571: I/TIOverlay(1419): Setting position X65/Y0/W959/H600
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/TIOverlay(1419): REQUEST FOR LCD1
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/TIOverlay(1419): found Panel Id @ [0], displayname [lcd2]
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/TIOverlay(1419): found Display Manager @ [2], managername [2lcd]
05-12 09:18:38.571: I/TIOverlay(1419): Position/X65/Y0/W959/H600/R270/A255/Z1
05-12 09:18:38.571: I/TIOverlay(1419): Adjusted Position/X65/Y0/W600/H958
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/TIOverlay(3543): Num of Buffers = 2
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/TIOverlay(3543): LCD[0] NAME[lcd2]
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/TIOverlay(3543): LCD[0] PATH[/sys/devices/platform/omapdss/display0/enabled]
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/TIOverlay(3543): LCD[0] timings[46000,1024/160/150/10,600/12/20/3
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/TIOverlay(3543): ]
05-12 09:18:38.571: E/TIOverlay(3543): Can't open the file[/sys/devices/platform/omapdss/display1/name]
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/TIOverlay(3543): lcd name get failed (maybe because device has less displays than max allowed)
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/TIOverlay(3543): MANAGER[0] NAME[lcd]
05-12 09:18:38.571: D/TIOverlay(3543): MANAGER[1] NAME[tv]
05-12 09:18:38.579: D/TIOverlay(3543): MANAGER[2] NAME[2lcd]
05-12 09:18:38.579: D/TIHardwareRenderer(3543): Overlay Buffer Count [as recommneded] 9
05-12 09:18:38.579: D/TIOverlay(3543): overlay_resizeInput 768x1120 9
05-12 09:18:38.602: I/OMXCodec(3543): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER] allocating 4 buffers of size 622592 on input port
05-12 09:18:38.633: I/OMXCodec(3543): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER] allocating 9 buffers of size 6881280 on output port
05-12 09:18:38.641: D/SeekTestActivity(3857): seeking
05-12 09:18:38.657: I/ActivityManager(1419): Displayed com.test.seek/.SeekTestActivity: +358ms
05-12 09:18:38.657: I/LAB126(1481): StatusBarService hears intent. action: com.lab126.intent.TOP_WINDOW_CHANGED
05-12 09:18:38.657: I/LAB126(1481):  window changed
05-12 09:18:38.672: D/SeekTestActivity(3857): seek complete
05-12 09:18:38.688: I/TIOverlay(1419): Setting position X65/Y0/W899/H600
05-12 09:18:38.688: D/TIOverlay(1419): REQUEST FOR LCD1
05-12 09:18:38.688: D/TIOverlay(1419): found Panel Id @ [0], displayname [lcd2]
05-12 09:18:38.688: D/TIOverlay(1419): found Display Manager @ [2], managername [2lcd]
05-12 09:18:38.688: I/TIOverlay(1419): Position/X65/Y0/W899/H600/R270/A255/Z1
05-12 09:18:38.688: I/TIOverlay(1419): Adjusted Position/X65/Y0/W600/H898
05-12 09:18:38.727: D/dalvikvm(1481): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1095K, 51% free 3456K/7047K, external 2508K/2989K, paused 2ms+3ms
05-12 09:18:39.641: D/SeekTestActivity(3857): playing movie
05-12 09:18:39.696: D/Omap4ALSA(3543): open called for devices 00000002 in mode 0 channels 00000000...
05-12 09:18:39.719: I/Omap4ALSA(3543): Using ping-pong!
05-12 09:18:39.719: I/Omap4ALSA(3543): Buffer size: 4096
05-12 09:18:39.719: I/Omap4ALSA(3543): Latency: 92879
05-12 09:18:39.758: D/TIOverlay(3543): Crop Win/X32/Y24/W600/H1024
05-12 09:18:39.758: D/TIOverlay(3543): REQUEST FOR LCD1
05-12 09:18:39.758: D/TIOverlay(3543): found Panel Id @ [0], displayname [lcd2]
05-12 09:18:39.758: D/TIOverlay(3543): found Display Manager @ [2], managername [2lcd]
05-12 09:18:39.766: I/Omap4ALSA(3543): Initialized ALSA PLAYBACK device 'plughw:0,0'
05-12 09:18:39.766: E/AudioHardwareALSA(3543): RE-OPEN AFTER STANDBY:: took 70 msecs
05-12 09:18:39.774: D/SeekTestActivity(3857): seek complete
```

Comment: By the way this is built with 2.1 SDK and running on Kindle.

Comment: Perhaps you should just structure your program to deal with this possibility rather than worry about why.

Comment: @Chris, that's a pretty snarky suggestion.  I'm sure the OP will have to deal with this one way or another, the question (reading between the lines) is "am I doing something wrong to evoke this behavior, or is this a bug in Android".  That's a perfectly legitimate thing to "worry" about!

Comment: @Dr.Dedel I would not assume that it is a bug.  It could very well be a normal consequence of the internal operation of the media player - it may actually "need" to do an implicit seek when playback starts, especially if it doesn't start from the beginning.  While knowing if you are doing something wrong could be good, absent finding documentation which states this should not be happening, code that makes fewer assumptions would be more robust, especially against any subtle changes in future versions of the media player.

Comment: @SeaRisk, my experience with seek is that it's extremely unpredictable across devices. For one thing, it tends to not jump to the actual millisecond you're asking it to go to, and depending on the media and device combo will do things totally differently. I don't know what's causing your particular issue though, sorry.

Comment: @Chris, I wasn't saying the OP should assume anything. I was only saying that it's a totally legitimate question, and your suggestion implied that it's not.

Comment: does it work differently on other devices? how about the emulator? i wonder if you can just deal with it working this way or not.

Comment: Thanks all. Unpredictability across devices is what I was afraid of, after getting this result. I'm in no position to check that.

Comment: But: it might also have to do with what kind of movie I'm playing or how I'm playing it. I have this other thing that happens that seems weird to me: the time it takes from when I issue the start() command to when the movie actually starts is greater than the time it takes to prepare the movie. Is that normal? Or does that happen to everyone? No idea. But it seems weird. I would have thought the whole idea of preparing a movie was so that it would start when you told it to.

Comment: I know, life is probably too short, but if anyone feels like making a new project, putting in the above code (no xml needed), putting their own movie in and reporting the results, that would be fun for me. (I just have this one device and I can't get movies to play on the emulator.)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I cannot add comments to your question, but I'm having the same problem. 
I also noticed that, when the `onSeekComplete` is called the first time and you output `currentMediaPostition()`, it returns the same media position as it was called through `seekTo(msec)`; which is fine.

But the second call to `onSeekComplete` (when the media starts) will output an other value (up to multiple seconds more or even less).

So I think the second call comes from the `start()` method. If you raise the delay from 1000ms to 3000ms, the call comes also later..