# Android MediaPlayer seeks to wrong position

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm using android's MediaPlayer to play .mp3 files. This function should seek to position 30 sec greater than the current one

```
fun jumpForward() {
            val offset = 30_000
            val old = mMediaPlayer.currentPosition
            val new = if (old + offset < mPlayedBook.duration) old + offset else mPlayedBook.duration
            Log.d("ProgressBar", "PlayerPresenter.rePlayFront, old: $old, new: $new")
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(new)
        }
```

But sometimes progress  bar's pointer jumps to wrong position. Sometimes even backwards. To track the wrong behaviour I put logs in onSeekComplete callback:

```
override fun onSeekComplete(mp: MediaPlayer) {
    Log.d("ProgressBar", "BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition: ${mp.currentPosition / 1000}")
    SystemClock.sleep(200)
    Log.d("ProgressBar", "BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition: ${mp.currentPosition / 1000}")
}
```

And here's an example log output. Here I'm calling jumpForward() method a few times in a row:

```
`04-29 13:36:47.091 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onPrepared, currentPosition: 153
04-29 13:36:47.151 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, before delay: 127
04-29 13:36:47.361 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, after delay: 127
04-29 13:36:55.621 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: PlayerPresenter.rePlayFront, old: 131, new: 161
04-29 13:36:55.631 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, before delay: 161
04-29 13:36:55.831 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, after delay: 100
04-29 13:36:57.071 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: PlayerPresenter.rePlayFront, old: 101, new: 131
04-29 13:36:57.091 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, before delay: 131
04-29 13:36:57.301 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, after delay: 54
04-29 13:36:58.731 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: PlayerPresenter.rePlayFront, old: 56, new: 86
04-29 13:36:58.741 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, before delay: 86
04-29 13:36:58.941 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, after delay: 71
04-29 13:37:00.481 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: PlayerPresenter.rePlayFront, old: 73, new: 103
04-29 13:37:00.521 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, before delay: 103
04-29 13:37:00.721 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, after delay: 85
04-29 13:37:02.251 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: PlayerPresenter.rePlayFront, old: 87, new: 117
04-29 13:37:02.281 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, before delay: 117
04-29 13:37:02.481 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, after delay: 117
04-29 13:37:03.991 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: PlayerPresenter.rePlayFront, old: 118, new: 148
04-29 13:37:04.011 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, before delay: 148
04-29 13:37:04.211 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, after delay: 123
04-29 13:37:05.711 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: PlayerPresenter.rePlayFront, old: 124, new: 154
04-29 13:37:05.721 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, before delay: 154
04-29 13:37:05.931 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, after delay: 128
04-29 13:37:07.571 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: PlayerPresenter.rePlayFront, old: 130, new: 160
04-29 13:37:07.591 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, before delay: 160
04-29 13:37:07.801 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, after delay: 114
04-29 13:37:09.661 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: PlayerPresenter.rePlayFront, old: 116, new: 146
04-29 13:37:09.681 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, before delay: 146
04-29 13:37:09.881 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, after delay: 121
04-29 13:37:11.611 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: PlayerPresenter.rePlayFront, old: 123, new: 153
04-29 13:37:11.621 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, before delay: 153
04-29 13:37:11.821 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, after delay: 127
04-29 13:37:13.501 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: PlayerPresenter.rePlayFront, old: 129, new: 159
04-29 13:37:13.511 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, before delay: 159
04-29 13:37:13.721 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, after delay: 132
04-29 13:37:15.061 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: PlayerPresenter.rePlayFront, old: 133, new: 163
04-29 13:37:15.091 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, before delay: 163
04-29 13:37:15.291 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, after delay: 135
04-29 13:37:16.481 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: PlayerPresenter.rePlayFront, old: 137, new: 167
04-29 13:37:16.521 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, before delay: 167
04-29 13:37:16.721 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, after delay: 104
04-29 13:37:17.691 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: PlayerPresenter.rePlayFront, old: 105, new: 135
04-29 13:37:17.701 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, before delay: 135
04-29 13:37:17.911 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, after delay: 67
04-29 13:37:18.811 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: PlayerPresenter.rePlayFront, old: 68, new: 98
04-29 13:37:18.821 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, before delay: 98
04-29 13:37:19.031 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, after delay: 81
04-29 13:37:20.381 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: PlayerPresenter.rePlayFront, old: 83, new: 113
04-29 13:37:20.411 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, before delay: 113
04-29 13:37:20.621 27366-27366/ru.orgin.glagol.debug D/ProgressBar: BookPlayer.onSeekComplete, currentPosition, after delay: 56
```

The 'before delay' log shows current position correctly, as it supposed to be after seekTo() call. But 'after delay' one (I've put that 200 ms delay on purpose) often shows wrong position, sometimes extremely wrong.

Is this a bug in MediaPlayer or might it be something else? Is there way to overcome the problem?

**UPDATE:** One more issue seems to be related to all kinds of mp3 files (VBR and CBR).

```
 override fun onPrepared(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
        isPreparing = false
        isPrepared = true

        mp?.start()
        mp?.seekTo(mProgressSeconds * 1000)
        mp?.setOnBufferingUpdateListener { _, percent ->
            bufferEndPercent = percent.toFloat() / 100
        }
        listeners.forEach { it.onPrepared() }
    }
```

In this function everything works fine. Except of on some devices, if `mProgressSeconds` value is more than roughly 12 minutes, MediaPlayer fails to seek to the correct position and starts playing from almost the beginning of the file.

Comment: is this android native java code?

Comment: it's written in kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Most of the issues related to seeking in my case were caused by VBR type of mp3 files. Whereas in case of CBR *almost* everything worked fine. So solution to this might be converting files to CBR, if possible. I've done it with Audacity app.

**Update:** There're few topics more or less related to my update in the question above. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565627/android-mediaplayer-video-seek-causes-onseekcomplete-to-be-called-twice) for example. But the simplest solution I've found is to add a small delay into onPrepared method:

```
override fun onPrepared(mp: MediaPlayer) {
    isPreparing = false
    isPrepared = true

    SystemClock.sleep(200)
    mp.start()
    Log.d("progress", "BookPlayer.onPrepared: $mProgressSeconds, currentPosition: ${mp.currentPosition / 1000}")
    mp.seekTo(mProgressSeconds * 1000)

    mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener { _, percent ->
        bufferEndPercent = percent.toFloat() / 100
    }
    listeners.forEach { it.onPrepared() }
}
```

It seems like onPrepared is being called a little earlier than it is actually initialized. So, with that small delay everything worked as expected.